# Using Native PHP Class inside laravel Framework

Tags: php, laravel

How can I use PHP native class( like SoapClient) inside laravel Framework?

Comment: Just toss it in your vendor directory and add it to your autoload config file.

Comment: agree with @bassxzero but also make sure you namespace your class if not already !!

Comment: What do you mean by "toss it in your vendor" directory? It's a native PHP class, you can use it from absolutely anywhere in your project. Just bear in mind that if you're working in a class that's in a namespace other than the root, you will need to reference it with a backslash (`\SoapClient`) or `use` it (`use SoapClient`)

Comment: @Jonathon I imagine that SoapClient is part of some 3rd party library like PHPMailer or FastRoute. Laravel suggests that you story 3rd party classes, libraries, etc in the vendor directory.

Comment: @Jonathon I tried using this. But Class SoapClient not found error is coming.

Comment: SoapClient is not a 3rd party class, it comes with PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

Comment: @DIPAKKUMARSINGH Can you post some code to show how you're using the SoapClient?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Didn't realize he was talking about the native one. Your server probably doesn't have it installed/configured.

Answer (score 6):

You can use native PHP classes like you would any other class in your project. You don't need to do anything special. The only consideration you might have to make is that if you want to use a native class such as SoapClient in a non-root namespace, you need to either `use` it:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use SoapClient; // use the SoapClient

class YourController extends Controller
{
    public function yourMethod()
    {
        $client = new SoapClient(...);
    }
}
```

...or reference the root namespace by preceding the class name with a backslash.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class YourController extends Controller
{
    public function yourMethod()
    {
        $client = new \SoapClient(...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The native classes are in the global namespace, so `$client = new \SoapClient($wsdl);` should work

Comment: I tried using this. But Class SoapClient not found error is coming.

Comment: @DIPAKKUMARSINGH just install soap in your server.

Answer (score 0):

Use `phpinfo()` and see if soap is instaled and enabled.